# How to use XSLT to match nodes where an attribute falls in a range of values specified by a variable?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

In my XSLT, I have a collection of nodes called `MyProducts` with each node having a `ProductId` node.

I want to read another node called `ProductCatalog` that contains a list of product Ids and then select only the products from `MyProducts` that have a product Id in `ProductCatalog`.

To that end, I've written an XSLT variable that gets the valid Ids:

```
<xsl:variable name="ValidIds" select="ProductCatalog/ProductId" />
<xsl:variable name="MyProductsWithValidId" select="ProductCatalog(... />
```

I think there ought to be some function I can complete this XSLT with that specifies that I want only nodes from ProductCatalog where the ProductId is contained in the `ValidIds` variable.

How do I do this?  My XSLT engine is running XSLT-2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="MyProductsWithValidId" select="ProductCatalog[ProductId=$ValidIds]"/>
```

In XSLT 1 and XSLT 2 you can compare with multiple values on either side of the `=`.  The processor checks each of one side with each of the other, and as soon as any comparison is `true()` the result `true()` is returned.  `false()` is only returned when all possible comparisons have been made.

So you will know that either none of the comparisons are true, or at least one of the comparisons is true, but you won't know which one or ones.

A formal way in XSLT 2 is to say:

```
<xsl:variable name="MyProductsWithValidId" 
              select="ProductCatalog[some $v in $ValidIds satisfies ProductId=$v]"/>
```

... but I prefer just using the `=` myself.